# AgGrid with ngx-perfect-scrollbar

Tags: angular, scrollbar, ag-grid-angular, ngx-perfect-scrollbar

I have implemented an example where [Ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) uses [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar#how-to-use) but I have a problem on horizontal scrollbar.

This is shown only when the mouse is hover the bottom area of the grid.
[image]

I would like to see both scrollbars when the mouse is hover the grid. How can I fix that issue?

Here the project: https://aggrid-ngx-perfect-scrollbar.stackblitz.io

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties that enable/disable scroll either in the X/Y axis.

1. suppressScrollX - Disable X-axis
2. suppressScrollY - Disable Y-axis

Both properties are set to false by default. This means that if both properties are set to false then you can scroll in both ways and the scrollbar will be visible on hover.

**If you post the code of a specific section (HTML or TS file) then I can easily assist you more because you only provide the stackblitz link that contains only output**